# hw to resize image ionic framework in grid view

Tags: ionic-framework

I ve got this code, i want to reset images dimensions with css , any help ?

```
<ion-content class="categories">
    <ion-row>
    <ion-col size='6' size-sm="4" size-md="3" *ngFor="let category of data.mainCategories" (click)="getProducts(category.id)">
    <ion-card class="category-card" class="ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated" mode="md">
      <ion-img alt="" src="{{category.image?.src}}"></ion-img>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title [innerHTML]="category.name"></ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
    </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```css
ion-img {
        object-fit: resize;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
```